# Decrease font size of all Menu Items in El Capitan

Tags: font, resolution

I have a 27" external monitor. The 1080p fonts are oversized: I know how to decrease them in individual apps - but what about the OS/X top menu bar? Note: i have already chosen the highest available display resolutions - nothing more to do in that sector.
[image]

Comment: 'highest available'... is that actually the monitor's native resolution? Seems a bit low for a 27" screen. I'd expect one to be 1440p [2560x1440]

Comment: That's a separate issue; the monitor supports 1440p but I do not (yet) have the proper cables.  This question is still valid: when having a 1080p available then let's figure out how to get the smallest fonts possible.

Comment: It's not really a separate issue - as you cannot change the menu bar font size, except by changing the monitor resolution...

Comment: @Tetsujin  If in fact the font size can not be changed - then feel free to add an answer as such.  If that's the facts then so it is.